# Rails cache from the console returning nothing nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-console

I am unable to see anything in the cache from the console in either development or production.

For development, I have turned on caching and set it to memory store, in production I use the dalli gem and Memcachier on Heroku.

Every key I try comes back nil.

However, in development, if I put in a `binding.pry` before somewhere I'm doing a `Rails.cache.fetch`, I can do a `Rails.cache.read` there and see something returning, and indeed if so, execution does not go in to the `fetch`'s block.

From the console, if I try `Rails.cache.read`ing the same key that just returned a cached result in the `pry` breakpoint console, I get nothing. It seems like the console has a separate cache, as if from the console I do `Rails.cache.write("whatever", "blah")` and `Rails.cache.read("whatever")`, I get "blah" in return, as expected.

Is there a way to experiment with the cache for a running server from the console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your cache store: the memory store just stores everything in the process's memory, so every instance of the application will have a separate cache. In particular the console won't see anything that is set from the running web application.

You could use the file store (which stores data in temporary files in tmp) or you could also use dalli store locally - memcached is very easy to run.

Comment: Alright, that works for development, I'm still getting nothing in production though, but I will accept your answer because it does answer the question I asked. For fragment caching in a view, where I do `- cache("the_key") do` in HAML, can I access that from the console using Rails.cache.read? Even after switching to file store, it does not seem so, even in development. How can I get this cached stuff?

Comment: NM, I found my own answer, using `ActionController::Base.new.fragment_cache_key("the_key")` I get the slightly modified cache key (in this case, with `view/` prepended to it), and can read with `Rails.cache.read` and that modified one or just do `ActionController::Base.new.read_fragment("the_key")` with the unmodified key to read. Thanks for your answer!